# Determine which country a user is in

Tags: mysql, location

Okay, I'm aware this question has been asked before, but I'm after a way that doesn't use an external API. I want to find the best way I could do it from my servers.

At the moment, I only have my database determine the users city in the UK (Not yet worldwide), which I've achieved using the Haversine equation:

```
PROCEDURE 'closestCity'(_lat1 decimal(10,7), _lng1 decimal(10,7):

SELECT id,city,6371*(2*ATAN2(SQRT(SIN(RADIANS(lat-_lat1)/2)*SIN(RADIANS(lat-_lat1)/2)+
SIN(RADIANS(lng-_lng1)/2)*SIN(RADIANS(lng-_lng1)/2)
*COS(RADIANS(_lat1))*COS(RADIANS(lat))),
SQRT(1-SIN(RADIANS(lat-_lat1)/2)*SIN(RADIANS(lat-_lat1)/2)+SIN(RADIANS(lng-_lng1)/2)*
SIN(RADIANS(lng-_lng1)/2)*COS(RADIANS(_lat1))*COS(RADIANS(lat))))) as distance 
FROM LOCCITY ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1;
```

I've managed to get hold of the worldwide city database, which is 143000+ entries long. So my thought was to first determine the users country, and have separate City tables for each country. The only issue I've thought that could arise (As is currently occurring slightly with finding the users city), is that when I use the Haversine equation, it will find the closest long and lat of the center point of the country.

This isn't too bad in some cases, but take for example Russia. If you are to the west of Russia, and I used the Haversine equation in this way, it would most likely say you was in Kazakhstan ...

So, the solution I thought of, was to create 'border points' long and lat, and use the Haversine equation against those instead to find which country the user was in.

Does anyone know of any database that has these 'border points' or whether a different equation is needed to find which city they are in? Or If I'm going about it completely the wrong way ...

**UPDATE**

So I've updated my database on my test rig to include all worldwide cities ... And it takes 1.2seconds to complete one query using the procedure above. It's not the fastest test rig, and I'll have to wait til I put it on my actual server to get real results, but it does show that using my current procedure to find a location isn't going to be viable ... Still, 143000 haversine equations a second isn't bad Lol ... I was impressed

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

So I thought of a good way I can reduce the amount of calculations. The first step will be to determine a group of possible countries they could be in, by using the provided Latitude, so for example, if it was a longitude of more than -10, but less than 0, this would include the UK, Ireland and a few others ... Then to find out which of those countries the user is in, I can use the 'Winding number algorithm' on rough border points (I found this at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) ... It's actually pretty easy how it works, basically, you take the angles from the users point to the border points, and if they add up to 360, then they are in the polygon (Country) :D ... And then I can use the haversine equation to find the city ...  I will test my previous method, and the new method (If I can find country polygons, or do them myself Lol) on my servers, and post the results ... Hopefully there is a big difference in run time.

**FINAL UPDATE**

Okay, my first question was 'Determine which country a user is in' ... But the reason I asked this is because I wanted to reduce the amount of Haversine equations my server had to do. But, I thought of another way to do this :D ... Basically, I have split the earth down into 'squares' 5longx5lat in size. I then created a table for the cities in each sqaure (612 tables in total). Then, I use PHP to determine which square the user is in, and include the surrounding squares for tolerance, and then do the haversine equation with those cities. Here it is in action, using random lat and long:

```
    $foundglng=false;
    $foundglat=false;
    $gridlng=-180;
    $gridlat=-85;
    $grid=1;
    $error=0;
    $lng=rand(-180,179)+(rand(0,9999999)/10000000);
    $lat=rand(-85,85)+(rand(0,9999999)/10000000);
    while($foundglng==false) {
        if($lng>=$gridlng&&$lng<=$gridlng+9.9999999) {
            $foundglng=true;
            while($foundglat==false) {
                if($lat>=$gridlat&&$lat<=$gridlat+9.9999999) {
                    $foundglat=true;
                } else {
                    $grid+=36;
                    $gridlat+=10;
                    if($gridlat>86) {
                        $error=1;
                        $foundglat=true;
                        $foundglng=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $grid+=1;
            $gridlng+=10;
            if($gridlng>181) {
                $error=1;
                $foundglat=true;
                $foundglng=true;
            }
        }
    }
    $sgarray=NULL;
    $sgarray=array();
    $sgarray[]=$grid;
    $sgarray[]=$grid-37;
    $sgarray[]=$grid-36;
    $sgarray[]=$grid-35;
    $sgarray[]=$grid-1;
    $sgarray[]=$grid+1;
    $sgarray[]=$grid+35;
    $sgarray[]=$grid+36;
    $sgarray[]=$grid+37;
    foreach($sgarray as $key=>$sg) {
        if($sg<1||$sg>612) {
            $sgarray[$key]='GRID' . $grid;
        } else {
            $sgarray[$key]='GRID' . $sg;
        }
    }
    mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("db_location") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT id,city,6371*
        (2*ATAN2(SQRT(SIN(RADIANS(lat-$lat)/2)
        *SIN(RADIANS(lat-$lat)/2)+SIN(RADIANS(lng-$lng)/2)
        *SIN(RADIANS(lng-$lng)/2)*COS(RADIANS($lat))
        *COS(RADIANS(lat))),SQRT(1-SIN(RADIANS(lat-$lat)/2)
        *SIN(RADIANS(lat-$lat)/2)+SIN(RADIANS(lng-$lng)/2)*
        SIN(RADIANS(lng-$lng)/2)*COS(RADIANS($lat))*COS(RADIANS(lat))))) 
        as distance FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM $sgarray[0]
        UNION SELECT * FROM $sgarray[1] 
        UNION SELECT * FROM $sgarray[2] 
        UNION SELECT * FROM $sgarray[3]
        UNION SELECT * FROM $sgarray[4]
        UNION SELECT * FROM $sgarray[5]
        UNION SELECT * FROM $sgarray[6]
        UNION SELECT * FROM $sgarray[7]
        UNION SELECT * FROM $sgarray[8]) as temp1
        ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1;");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['city'] . '</br>';
    }
```

This takes between 0.1 to 0.2 seconds to run. So, compared to my original procedure (Which took 1.2, I've divided the time by 10 :D ... A little fine tuning, maybe by decreasing the size of the grid squares,I could potentiality decrease this further ...